# Why is the xdg-mime script not found when attempting to install a new MIME type?

Tags: mime-type

I've been running Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 for a few months now (quite smoothly, I might add). That said, a couple days ago I used the “xdg-mime” script to register a MIME type and associate it with my own application. I then used xdg-icon-resource to link a chosen icon with the type. So everything worked exactly as expected… Then yesterday, I attempt to do the same thing for another application of mine (PipeWrench) and I immediately run into problems attempting to register the new MIME type (via an “xdg-mime install…”). It errors with “Command ‘xdg-mime’ not found…” (see screenshot). So, I try the same command using a fully-qualified path to the script and it errors with “No such file or directory” -- even though the script clearly exists in the "/usr/bin" folder. As you can see, I then ran a different invocation of the very same “xdg-mime” script (to query a file’s MIME type) and that works fine regardless of whether I invoke the script fully-qualified or not! I’ve never seen anything like this before. Can anyone provide a clue as to why the xdg-mime script in "/usr/bin" runs just fine when querying a file's MIME type but it can't even be found whenever I try to use it to add a new MIME type? Have I entered the Twilight Zone?[image]

Here's the contents of the pipewrench-pip.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
   <mime-type type="application/pipewrench">
   <comment>PipeWrench pipe file</comment>
   <glob pattern="*.pip"/>
  </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
```

Comment: Did you type the original command - or copy-paste it from somewhere? I wonder if a non-ascii character slipped in there (perhaps a unicode en-dash in place of the hyphen)?

Comment: OMG, bingo! When it initially happened, I had dragged the text into the terminal and this same thought had occurred to me as well and so I believe I repeated the command, but only by re-typing just the "xdg-mime" part and not the rest of the command (I must be an idiot). Thenceforth, I kept re-using the still flawed command in the terminal (using the up arrow)... I'm gonna have to watch out for this in the future... Thank you so much! How do I go about accepting your answer as the solution?